# Why ghost of Eleanor Reigns tries to kill Max's father in Mirrors 2

Tags: plot-explanation, mirrors-2

In *Mirrors 2*, Eleanor Reigns takes revenge from the people who were responsible for her death. However, she tries to kill Max's father who was the owner of MayFlower Department Store, but he was not one of those people.

So why she tries to kill him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eleanor Reigns doesn't want to kill max's father, she need his help and needed him to do what she wants.

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirrors_2)

> Max sees his father's face covered in cuts in a puddle then races to his father's house. Jack is almost killed by his reflection, after Max made it to his house and hints to whoever is manipulating the mirrors that he would do whatever she wants him to do if she spares his father.

Max is emotionally disturbed because he causes the car accident that killed his fiancee. He has been under treatment with psychological doctor.

Max's father invites Max to replace the security guard to help Max's condition. Max got his first vision of Eleanor at the store. He was unsure whether his visions are side effects of his prescription sleeping pills or actual reality.

Max saw Eleanor may because of his condition due to the serious car accident , and when Eleanor finds out that Max can see her she thought she could use his help in revenge, and she may needed a way to contact her sister.